# Pip Permission Denied

Tags: python, pip

При установке любых библиотек через pip install получаю ошибку

Тут на примере aiogram (это роли не играет)

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/aiogram/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/aiogram/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/aiogram/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/aiogram/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/aiogram/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aiogram (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aiogram
```

Как это исправить?
Пробовал использовать разные точки подключения, ситуация не меняется.

Доп.Информация:

Windows 11 (22621.2134)
Python 3.11.4
pip 23.2.11

Comment: Тут важно всё: тип операционки, её версия, номер версии питона. А потом гуглить по всему сочетанию признаков.

Comment: @CrazyElf обновил вопрос

Comment: Хорошо. Далее. У вас просто сам питон через его инсталлятор установлен или какая-нибудь anaconda и в ней питон? И где и как вы pip запускаете - в командной строке? От администратора командную строку запускать пробовали?

Comment: @CrazyElf Просто чистый питон через инсталлятор. В командной строке - от администратора такая же история, всё что связано с VPN - удалил, бэндмрауэр отключил.

Comment: @CrazyElf вероятно это случилось после установки OpenServer, может он блокирует порт? Хотя на другой системе было всё в порядке

Comment: Я бы для начала попробовал какой-то более старый проверенный питон на той же машине поставить. В новых версиях всё время какие-то баги.

Comment: @CrazyElf Подскажите, пожалуйста, версию которая установлена у Вас, проверю

Comment: 3.8 считается довольно стабильной версией, например. У меня то стоит 3.10.6, но не чистый питон, а через mamba я его ставил.

Comment: @CrazyElf действительно, на версии 3.8.0 всё исправно заработало, напишите, пожалуйста, это как ответ, я отмечу его правильным. Большое спасибо.

Comment: Да я не уверен, будет ли это кому-то полезно. Новые версии всегда какие-то глючные, их потом исправляют понемногу. )  Хотите, сами ответ напишите )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Огромная благодарность @CrazyElf за помощь

`Новые версии всегда какие-то глючные, их потом исправляют понемногу.`

Проблему удалось решить откатом на более старую версию `python`, а конкретно - `3.8.0`